# Python Phonebook

Tags: python, dictionary

I Have searched for similar tasks but i have not found anyting comprehensive. I have been given a task to make a phonebook with the following requirements.

1. -add *name number* - adds a name and a number

   -lookup *name* – prints the number for name

   -alias *name newname* – adds a "nickname" to an already existing name

   -change *name number* – changes the number to an alredy existing name

   -save filename – Saves the phonebook to a file

   -load filename –Reads the file and throws away the phonebook in the memory(wat?) After this only the phonebook from the file should
   exist.

This is my code so far:

```
prompt = ('command (add/lookup/alias/change/save/load/quit/)')

phonebook = {}

run = True

while run:

command = raw_input(prompt)
if command == 'quit':
    run = False

elif command == 'add':
    name = raw_input('name?')
    number = raw_input ('number?')
    phonebook[name]=number

elif command == ('lookup'):
    name=raw_input ("Name?:")
    if name in phonebook:
        print name, phonebook[name]
    else:
        print "Does not exist"
```

So i need help on how to implement the *alias* and *change* commandos. The save and load i think i can figure out myself but any help on those will be appriciated aswell.

Thanks

Comment: I might use two dictionaries: one that maps names (and aliases) to arbitrary IDs, and another that pulls up the information from the ID. Aliases would effectively be identical to names. Or create a separate alias dictionary if you don't want aliases to be equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reformat your phonebook to a nested dictionary

```
phonebook = {
  "Steven": {"Alias": "Steve", "Number": "123-456-7890"}, 
  "Michael": {"Alias": "Mike", "Number": "987-654-3210"}
}
```

Then you could look things up like

```
>>> phonebook['Steven']['Number']
'123-456-7890'
```

Then your last two functions could be

```
elif command == ('alias'):
    name = raw_input ("Name?:")
    nickname = raw_input ("Alias?:")
    if name in phonebook:
        phonebook[name]['Alias'] = nickname
    else:
        print "Does not exist"

elif command == ('change number'):
    name = raw_input ("Name?:")
    number = raw_input ("Number?:")
    if name in phonebook:
        phonebook[name]['Number'] = number
    else:
        print "Does not exist"
```

**Edit**

```
elif command == 'add':
    name = raw_input('name?')
    number = raw_input ('number?')
    phonebook[name] = {'Alias': '', 'Number': number}

elif command == ('lookup'):
    name = raw_input ("Name?:")
    if name in phonebook:
        print name, phonebook[name]
    else:
        print "Does not exist"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show the inteded add and lookup code aswell. Im not familiar with using nested dictionary and i cant get them to work.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you